# Nextjs 13.4 does not trigger useEffect even with 'use client'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css, next.js13

i've been trying to set up useEffect into Nextjs 13.4 but seems like it's not getting triggered even with the 'use client' directive. has anybody faced a similar issue where the useEffect in Nextjs did not get fired even once?

**page.tsx**

```
'use client';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
const textList = [
   "text1",
   'text2',
   "text3",
   'text4',
];

export default function Home() {
  const [visibleIndex, setVisibleIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Create a timer to change the visible text index
    console.log('is this running?');
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setVisibleIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1);
    }, 3000); 

    // Clear the timer when the component unmounts
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [visibleIndex]);
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <div className="flex gap-10">
        <Link href="/">Home</Link>
        <Link href="/story">Story</Link>
      </div>
      <div>
         <h1 className="text-6xl font-bold">Title</h1>
         <div>
            {textList.map((text, index) => (
              <div
                key={index}
                className={`text-2xl ${
                index === visibleIndex ? 'animate-fade-in-up visible' : ''
                }`}
              >
              {text}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </main>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Above code is working, https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/crazy-forest-fkcgky, maybe check if everything has restarted and you are in dev mode etc?

Comment: I have this when using turbo pack bundler